# Android Webview does not implement CSS

Tags: android, css, html, jquery-mobile, webview

I am creating an Android Application with a webview.
I am planning to put all PHP, HTML5, CSS and Javascript files on a server. I am using JQuery Mobile framework.

Here is the code that opens the webview:

---

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl("http://thefinddroid.com/TriviaGame");
```

---

Here's the CSS file:

```
img.option {
    paddding:5px;
    border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#text_question {
    font-size:25px;
    text-align: center;
}
img.question {
    padding:5px;
    border:4px solid #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#offer {
    display:block;
    width:480px;
    margin:10px;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    color:#000000;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:3px solid #DBDBDB;
}
```

---

Here is a part of my HTML file that loads the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />
<script src="js/jqm_171.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqm120_alpha.js"></script>
```

---

Here's the HTML5 code inside the body tag:

```
    <body>
    <div align="center" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Trivia Game</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <h1>Question #1</h1>

                <img class="question" 
                                         src="images/q1.jpg" 
                                         align="center" />
                <div id="text_question">
                    <p>Which guitar is used in this picture?</p>
                </div>

                <table cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img class="option"
                             id="option_1" 
                             src="images/c1.jpg" 
                             onclick="selected_option(1)" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img class="option"   
                             id="option_2" 
                             src="images/c2.jpg" 
                             onclick="selected_option(2)" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <td>
                            <img class="option" 
                             id="option_3" 
                             src="images/c3.jpg" 
                             onclick="selected_option(3)" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img class="option" 
                             id="option_4" 
                             src="images/c4.jpg" 
                             onclick="selected_option(4)" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <br /> <br />
                <div id="offer">To learn more on Stylist :
                 Article, Links and Benfits - <a href="#">Click here</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
```

---

This is the scenario:

1. When I open the web page in my PC browser, everything works fine. All of my CSS styles work well.
2. When I open the web page in my Android browser for the first time (without reloading), the CSS styles are not displayed. But when I refresh it, it will display the CSS styles.
3. When I open the application that I created, CSS are not working. All of the CSS styles do not display in my app.

---

Screenshot of the Application (Does not implement CSS):[image: This is the screenshot of the application, it does not show CSS]

---

Screenshot from an Android Browser (Implements CSS)[image: This is the screenshot of the browser, it shows CSS]

Comment: Does it do the same thing in Android's browser?

Comment: @NoBugs Each screenshot is described in my question. The first one is the screenshot of the app, and the second one is the screenshot of the browser of my Android device. It is different, the browser implements the css, while the application does not.

Comment: i know this is old but have you tried absolute URLs to your CSS?

Answer (score -6):

Android wont supports **table** tag. In your html contains the table tag that's why u did't get proper view.

**Android only supports following html tags.**

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

Comment: FYI, I was not the one to give your answer a down vote. Can you give me the source of your answer? Some documentations or articles maybe.. I cannot thoroughly understand what you are stating.

Comment: If you look at my code, I have also used div for CSS, and still it does not appear.

Comment: So Android doesn't support `<script>`, `<style>`, `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>`, `<title>`, `<table>` and other tags? Which version of Android is this basic? Please cite a source for your answer.